# How do I reduce this data frame by groups?

Tags: r, reduce

I have the following

```
t <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Alice", "Bob",
"Jane Doe", "John Doe"), class = "factor"), school = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Alice School",
"Bob School", "Someother School", "Someschool College"), class = "factor"),
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"),
    question = structure(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L,
    4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L,
    2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("q1", "q2", "q3",
    "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8"), class = "factor"), mark = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
    1L), subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name",
"school", "group", "question", "mark", "subject"), row.names = c(7L,
15L, 23L, 31L, 3L, 11L, 19L, 27L, 8L, 16L, 24L, 32L, 4L, 12L,
20L, 28L, 6L, 14L, 22L, 30L, 2L, 10L, 18L, 26L, 5L, 13L, 21L,
29L, 1L, 9L, 17L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I need to produce a data frame in which each student has one combined mark for each subject. The combination is simply a sum of the marks on each question. So, for example, Jane Doe will have 3 on subject C and 2 on subject M. I've been banging my head for long enough with `Reduce` and other approaches. I could possibly solve this in a very procedural way, but if I could do that with a one-liner (or close approximation), I'd be happier. I'm sure it can be done...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said it in your question; you want to `group_by` student and subject and compute the sum

```
library(tidyverse)
asdf %>%
  group_by(name, subject) %>%
  summarise(score = sum(mark))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t)[, sum(mark), by = list(name, subject)]
```

Answer (score 3):

And just for completeness, base R:

```
aggregate(mark ~ name + subject, data=t, sum)
```

This says "aggregate the response variable `mark` by the grouping variables `name` and `subject`, using `sum` as the aggregation function".